# React/NodeJS won't speak via localhost in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I'm working to setup a Node backend to feed data and communicate with ReactJS for my frontend. Ultimately I am developing new company software to replace our current Transportation System.

I utilize Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 - for my own reasons for my business - and I simply cannot get my ReactJS frontend with Socket.IO to communicate with my nodeJS backend with Socket.IO on http://localhost:4000/.

This is my App.js in my react frontend when it calls

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import ioClient from 'socket.io-client';
import './App.css';

var socket;

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:4000/'
    };
    socket = ioClient(this.state.endpoint);
  }
```

This is my nodeJS index for the backend

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server running on port 4000')
});

const sqlCon = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin-user',
    password: 'admin-pass',
    database: 'sample'
});

sqlCon.connect( (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected!');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
});

server.listen(4000, "localhost", () => {
    console.log('Node Server Running on 4000')
});
```

I can get it to communicate via my actual Public IP address, but not via localhost. I really don't want to expose my backend on my public IP address to communicate with it for all users. This has probably been asked before, but I honestly can't find a clear answer for it anywhere and I've been looking for 3 days now. Node has no problem executing, and like I said if I create the socket.io connection from the public IP, I can get it to communicate and as far as I can tell node has no problem running the rest of the script as it connects to mariaDB no problem.

This is the error I keep receiving in my Chrome console.

```
polling-xhr.js:271 GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MvBS0bE net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
polling-xhr.js:271 GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MvBS3H8 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm running React via npm start for the time being, so my localhost:3000 is being reverse proxied to nginx for my React frontend to be visible on my public EC2 IP via port 80.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: About network technically, If you try to create a local system, you need to connect to the hosting ip of your server. For example, you have a local network with your server running node has local ip is 192.168.1.190, your SocketIO should connect to that local ip address to run all your system locally. If i undertand your question right.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a cross origin request issue. Have you tried to enable CORS on your app. You can also use proxy in your react app `package.json` if you do not want to enable cors on your app.

In your react app package.json you can add

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:4000"
```

Comment: CORS is enabled on my Node Server and i still run into this error.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the port you are using isn't available in the server-side when it's running.

Use the server-side port like this,

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, "localhost", () => {
    console.log('Node Server Running on 4000')
});
```

and on the client-side just connect to the app URL, like,

```
this.state = {
  endpoint: '/'
};
socket = ioClient(this.state.endpoint);
```

Comment: I don't see how this would make sense. If I made my endpoint '/' I would just be connecting to my client front-end as I have REACT's dev port 3000 forwarded to that location for nginx. I'm looking for REACT to connect to my backend Node using the localhost so that I don't have to expose Node to the public IP address.

Comment: So this gave me the idea to reverse proxy my nodeJS server into nginx and try to call my endpoint from the specified endpoint ('/nodeJS/') and that didn't work either.

Comment: in case of local, there might be an issue with proxy blockage or something... could you check whether you can connect from ur react app to your ip:port, eg. ur localhost ip like 192.168.45.42:3000.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean up your server a bit. Take this guy run him from whatever terminal or ide you use to get your server going.

```
let startTime = Date.now();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const compression = require('compression');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '32mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '32mb', extended: false }));
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
app.use(cors({ origin: 'null' }));
const request = require('request');
const port = 4000;
let pm2InstanceNumber = parseInt(process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE) || 0;
http.listen(port + pm2InstanceNumber, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('Listening http://localhost:%d in %s mode', port + pm2InstanceNumber);
    console.log('Time to server start: ' + (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000.0 + ' seconds');
    setTimeout(() => {
        try {
            process.send('ready');
        } catch (e) {}
    }, 2000);

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('Server running on port 4000')
    });
});
```

or just run `node filename.js` to serve this guy up.

Comment: I tried using this and installed the required dependencies and node won't even start with this code.